# An error occured while performing request: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, curl, drupal, camunda

I am working on integrating Drupal and Camunda. I am using Drupal Core 8.9.20. For the integration of Drupal and Camunda, I am following this official documentation of Camunda.

[Drupal Camunda Integration](https://camunda.com/blog/2017/01/integrating-camunda-drupal/)

I am done with the installation of the module in Drupal. For the configuration part, I have added this URL.

Platform REST base URL => http://localhost:8080/engine-rest (for distributions)

When I go to the **/invoice** URL and submit the form it gives the following error:

> An error occurred while performing request: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

I am running camunda on localhost:8080. I have tested the API in Postman using curl in both it is working but when I try to submit the form I got this error.

To troubleshoot and resolve this issue, I have performed the following steps:

1. Camunda is running on localhost:8080.
2. Removed firewall.
3. Tested with Postman and curl.

**How could I solve this Error?**